# Eclipse Quick Fix "I am feeling lucky"

Tags: eclipse

I absolutely **adore** Eclipse's `Quick Fix` functionality.

It is so useful, so smart, just so well implemented.. it could use a "final touch of nicety" as far as I am concerned: an *"I am feeling lucky"* shortcut.

If `COMMAND/CTRL 1` gives me a menu of Quick Fixes to choose from.. I'd like for something like `COMMAND/CTRL SHIFT 1` (I need to think a proper shortcut for this) to immediately choose the first (highest likelihood of being right) fix and implement it for me.

Can I already do this with existing features that allow keyboard shortcut customisation?

This is inspired by just how *good* the current guessing and ordering of options is. It is so good for me that *most of the time* I wanna choose the top option. I think any *"I am feeling lucky"* which can be undone by COMMAND/CTRL Z is a good candidate to being done with one click? I would exclude, of course, the changes that bring up a "choice dialog", like previewing source code changes with potential adverse side-effects..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible with Eclipse built-in tooling. There are some workarounds, that might fit your needs:

- Use some kind of keyboard macro tool (independent of Eclipse) to play the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> sequence when you hit your combination of choice.
- Some quickfixes can be assigned a keyboard shortcut in the keyboard preferences of Eclipse. So you could choose certain quickfixes directly (but not as the top suggestion).
- Some quickfixes are also available as save actions (for example "organize imports"). You should activate all those in the save actions, as you can then run them by just saving the file.

Comment: You are so helpful, as always... THANKS!